# data between classes is not being passed in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I want to assign a value of an integer data from a different class. So I did the following:

I want to assign a value declared as a property of class B from class A:

in B.h file

```
@interface B : UIViewController {
    int num;
}
@property(readwrite)int num ;
```

in B.m file

```
@synthesize num;
```

now In A.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)B *b;
```

then in A.m file

```
b=[[B alloc]init];
b.num=5;
```

the problem is when I NSLOG the num using

`NSLog(@"The Number is %d",num);`

in the B class it always shows 0, I have tried with `NSString` and it also passes NULL. I am stuck here, please any body can help?

Comment: What are you `NSLog`ing?  You're probably reading the ivar `num` and not the property `self.num`.

Comment: do you know how to write init method...it will be easier with init

Comment: Please lit me @RedDevil

Comment: are you using interface builder? Code will be slightly different, if you are using interface builder

Comment: yes, I am using interface builder

Comment: And how many instances of B do you create??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself this way

in class B

```
-(id)initwithParameters:(NSString *)parameter
{

    if(self == [super init])
    {
        // access the paramenter and store in yo u avariable    
    }
    return self;

}
```

In class a

```
[[class b alloc]initwithParameters:@"Something"];
```

Answer (score 2):

B.h file

```
@interface B : UIViewController{
      int num;
```

}

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil passingNum:(int)pNumber;

@end
```

B.m file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil passingNum:(int)pNumber{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        num = pNumber;

    }
    return self;
}
```

A.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)B *b;
```

A.h file

```
b = [[b alloc] initWithNibName:@"Here-WriteNameOF-XIB-file-associated-with-b" bundle:nil passingNum:5];
```